# Closed contour and essential singularity

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How to manage an essential singularity?

> $$I=\oint_{\gamma} e^{\frac{1}{z}}z^{-3}dz$$
>
> where gamma= circumference centered in z=0, radius=2.

Clearly z=0 is an essential singularity, so I tried to use the Laurent series..

$$I=\oint \frac{1}{z^3}\sum_0 ^\infty (\frac{1}{z})^n \frac{1}{n!}=\oint \sum_0 ^\infty \frac{1}{z^{n-3}} \frac{1}{n!}$$

I tried to obtain the $a_{-1}$ coefficient of the series.. that corresponds to the residual...  so the value of the integral should be $$I=2\pi i a_{-1} $$.. but I'm stuck, because if n=-1, I get the factorial of a negative number...

Comment: You should never, ever calculate a Laurent series with the definition. Usually much easier to find a Taylor series and fit it to your function. Find the Taylor series of $e^x$, replace $x$ with $1/z$, and multiply by $z^{-3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get
$$z^{-3}e^{1/z}=\frac1{z^3}+\frac1{z^4}+\frac1{2z^5}+\cdots.$$
The residue at $0$ (the $z^{-1}$ coefficient) is zero, so the contour
integral is zero.

Integrating $z^3e^{1/z}$ instead gives a more interesting answer!